# Bot Whatsapp não funciona

Tags: python

Estou começando meus estudos em Python e achei um guia para montar um robozinho que envia mensagens pelo whatsapp automaticamente.Montei tudo certinho segundo as intruções, mas mesmo assim não funciona.Abto o terminal e nada acontece

Meu código:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

class WhatsappBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mensagem = "Olar, fiz um robô e estou testando"
        self.grupos = ["Irmão"]
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('lang=pt-br')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'./chromedriver.exe')

    def EnviarMensagens(self):
    # <span dir="auto" title="Filhotas di mamães" class="ggj6brxn gfz4du6o r7fjleex g0rxnol2 lhj4utae le5p0ye3 l7jjieqr _11JPr">Filhotas di mamães <img crossorigin="anonymous" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" alt="" draggable="false" class="b40 emoji wa _11JPr" style="background-position: -80px -40px;"><img crossorigin="anonymous" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" alt="" draggable="false" class="b40 emoji wa _11JPr" style="background-position: -80px -40px;"><img crossorigin="anonymous" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" alt="" draggable="false" class="b128 emoji wa _11JPr" style="background-position: -60px -40px;"><img crossorigin="anonymous" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" alt="" draggable="false" class="b71 emoji wa _11JPr" style="background-position: -60px -40px;"></span>
    #  <div tabindex="-1" class="_3Uu1_">
    #<span data-testid="send" data-icon="send" class="">
        print('Oi gente, fiz um robo que manda mensagem')
        self.driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com')
        time.sleep(30)
        for  grupo in self.grupos:        
            grupo = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//span[@title='{grupo}']")
        time.sleep(3)
        grupo.click()
        chat_box = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3Uu1_')
        time.sleep(3)
        chat_box.click()
        chat_box.send_keys(self.mensagem)
        botao_enviar = self.diver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@data-icon='send']")
        time.sleep(3)
        botao_enviar.click()
        time.sleep(5)

bot = WhatsappBot()
bot.EnviarMensagens()
```

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vRX1.jpg)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Bom dia colega. Sou iniciante também em programação python. Tenho alguns bots desenvolvidos já e funcionam perfeitamente, mas, houve uma uma atualização do selenium em que mudou um pouco as formas dos comandos para achar algum elemento em um site, eu acho que é isso. Estou estudando isso nesse exato momento e encontrei a sua dúvida que é a minha também. Achei um link que acho que demostra essa alteração:

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

por exemplo, tente trocar o trecho: self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(

por: self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,

e:  self.driver.find_element_by_class_name(

por: self.driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Olá, bom dia! Agradeço sua ajuda, mas mesmo com essa correção ainda não funcionou. Aqui ele parece não reconhecer o comendo (BY). Olha só a mensagem que aparece:
"BY" is not defined  Pylance(reportUndefinedVariable)

Fiz exatamente como aparecia no link self.driver.find_elements(BY.XPATH,f"//span[@title='{grupo}']")